# Drop of events not working on fullcalendar when I add a script for showing events to the calendar

Tags: javascript

Hi there can I have this problem, I have this file and when I try to edit the events I add a script of events at the end to display the events on calendar as soon as I do that the events that are on the left side I cant drop them anymore
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnp36.jpg)

As you can see on the picture this events works fine before I add this script to the end of  file:

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      // defaultDate: '2018-03-12',
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: [


        {
          title: 'All Day Event ',
          start: '2018-09-01'
        },


      ]
    });

  });

</script>
```

So this is my file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!-- Favicon icon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="../../assets/images/favicon.png">
    <title></title>
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="../../assets/libs/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../../assets/extra-libs/calendar/calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
</head>

<body>

    <div id="main-wrapper">
       
        <aside class="left-sidebar">
            <!-- Sidebar scroll-->
            <div class="scroll-sidebar">
                <!-- Sidebar navigation-->
                <nav class="sidebar-nav">
          
                       

                        <li class="sidebar-item">
                            <a class="sidebar-link has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="javascript:void(0)
                                   " aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="icon-Error-404Window"></i>
                                <span class="hide-menu">Error Pages</span>
                            </a>
                            <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse first-level">
                            
                             
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                   
                    
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <!-- End Sidebar navigation -->
            </div>
            <!-- End Sidebar scroll-->
        </aside>
      
        <div class="page-wrapper">
          
            <div class="page-breadcrumb">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-5 align-self-center">
                        <h4 class="page-title">Calendar</h4>
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">

                        </div>
                    </div>
            
                </div>
            </div>
         
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-3 border-right p-r-0">
                                        <div class="card-body border-bottom">
                                            <h4 class="card-title m-t-10">Drag & Drop Event</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                    <div id="calendar-events" class="">
                                                        <div class="calendar-events m-b-20" data-class="bg-info"><i class="fa fa-circle text-info m-r-10"></i>Event One</div>
                                                        <div class="calendar-events m-b-20" data-class="bg-success"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success m-r-10"></i> Event Two</div>
                                                        <div class="calendar-events m-b-20" data-class="bg-danger"><i class="fa fa-circle text-danger m-r-10"></i>Event Three</div>
                                                        <div class="calendar-events m-b-20" data-class="bg-warning"><i class="fa fa-circle text-warning m-r-10"></i>Event Four</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!-- checkbox -->
                                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="drop-remove">
                                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="drop-remove">Remove after drop</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-new-event" class="btn m-t-20 btn-info btn-block waves-effect waves-light">
                                                            <i class="ti-plus"></i> Add New Event
                                                        </a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                                        <div class="card-body b-l calender-sidebar">
                                            <div id="calendar"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- BEGIN MODAL -->
                <div class="modal none-border" id="my-event">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title"><strong>Add Event</strong></h4>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body"></div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success save-event waves-effect waves-light">Create event</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-event waves-effect waves-light" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Modal Add Category -->
                <div class="modal fade none-border" id="add-new-event">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title"><strong>Add</strong> a category</h4>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label class="control-label">Category Name</label>
                                            <input class="form-control form-white" placeholder="Enter name" type="text" name="category-name" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label class="control-label">Choose Category Color</label>
                                            <select class="form-control form-white" data-placeholder="Choose a color..." name="category-color">
                                                <option value="success">Success</option>
                                                <option value="danger">Danger</option>
                                                <option value="info">Info</option>
                                                <option value="primary">Primary</option>
                                                <option value="warning">Warning</option>
                                                <option value="inverse">Inverse</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light save-category" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END MODAL -->
            </div>
      
        </div>
      
    </div>

    <script src="../../assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/extra-libs/taskboard/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch-improved.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/extra-libs/taskboard/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tether Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="../../assets/libs/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- apps -->
    <script src="../../dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/app.init.boxed.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/app-style-switcher.js"></script>
    <!-- slimscrollbar scrollbar JavaScript -->
    <script src="../../assets/libs/perfect-scrollbar/dist/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/extra-libs/sparkline/sparkline.js"></script>
    <!--Wave Effects -->
    <script src="../../dist/js/waves.js"></script>
    <!--Menu sidebar -->
    <script src="../../dist/js/sidebarmenu.js"></script>
    <!--Custom JavaScript -->
    <script src="../../dist/js/custom.min.js"></script>
    <!--This page JavaScript -->
    <script src="../../assets/libs/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/libs/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/pages/calendar/cal-init.js"></script>
    <script>
    </script>
 <script>

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      // defaultDate: '2018-03-12',
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: [


        {
          title: 'All Day Event',
          start: '2018-09-01'
        },
       
 
      ]
    });

  });

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

So this is my code sorry I don't know how to put my local files on snipet, I just thought maybe someone when sees the code would have an idea and help me I would  really appreciate it

Comment: Please give a read to [mcve] to figure out how to get your code down to the smallest amount needed for your question. You'll need to replace links to local copies of library files to ones on the internet starting with `https`. For instance, for fullcalendar, you can find links to files corresponding to your local files here: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/fullcalendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this code instead (taken from https://fullcalendar.io/docs/external-dragging-demo, I just updated it according to your ids and classes names):

```
    $(function() {

  // initialize the external events
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------

  $('#calendar-events .calendar-events').each(function() {

    // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
    $(this).data('event', {
      title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
      stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
    });

    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
    $(this).draggable({
      zIndex: 999,
      revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
      revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
    });

  });

    // initialize the calendar
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------

   $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      // defaultDate: '2018-03-12',
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      droppable: true,
      events: [


        {
          title: 'All Day Event ',
          start: '2018-09-01'
        },


      ]
    });

  });

    drop: function() {
      // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
      if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
        // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
        $(this).remove();
      }
    }
  });

});
```